# Mailgun - links are going in encrypted format in emails

Tags: email, hyperlink, mailgun, mail-server

Hope you are doing well.

I am using your free api for sending an email but when I sends any email using my mailgun configuration in email I am facing below problem:

In message suppose I am sending 'Click Here to Download' and wrap that string to anchor tag with url 'www.test.com' at that scenario in my email account I am getting 'Click here to Download' link but the url of that string becomes like below:

http://email.www.mydomain.com/c/eJxFzU0OgyAQQOHTyJIMzDDggkVj6j0maCoJ_qRibG9f202Tt_7eEMOAwEHlaMEweAvgyTvUwbNz2lgGfe-Yup6xITjPU89HqXlY667TOqsptpYdpjaJAAZPljAxSSBqjXUGkypxqnVr8NbY_uprjC-ZtzL-hGdc8j7lqossDyn5LdfoP8mLqvED-Lsx0Q

So can you please let me know how can I resolve it or what type of configuration I need to do ?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you include some code and other details about how you're running/what system/language/etc.?

Comment: Actually, we used mailgun plugin in my WordPress site.We just configure milgun account details from plugin backend nothing else.

Comment: Issues are resolved.

Comment: @ChiragPatel Can you provide some details about the solution? I am facing the same one and wondering what might be causing it.

Comment: Found the culprit. It was due to click tracking enabled in mailgun. Fixed now :)

Answer (score 2):

Add "X-Mailgun-Track-Clicks: no" to the Header.

For laravel users:

```
Mail::send('template', $array, function ($message) use ($subject, $email) {

    $message->from('mail@website.com','Hello')->to($email)->subject($subject)
        ->getSwiftMessage()
        ->getHeaders()
        ->addTextHeader('X-Mailgun-Track-Clicks', 'no');
});
```